# PHP Warning: failed to open stream: no such file or directory

Tags: php

I am working on local server, but I am having problem including files, even with full path given. eg, I have a file `/home/[user]/public_html/vt/test.php` like this:

```
<?php    
 include_once('/home/<user>/public_html/vt/Menu.php');
 print "included_once called.\n";     
?>
```

I got error in `error_log`:

```
failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

*/home/[user]/public_html/vt/Menu.php* exists, and access right is:

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 <user> apache 3906 Jul  5 08:43 <full/path/of/the/file>
```

The local documentRoot folder is set to (recursively):

```
drwxr-xr-x.  4 <user> apache     4096 Jul 26 14:06 public_html
```

So what is wrong?

Comment: *"So what is wrong?"* - The file or directory doesn't exist.

Comment: @deceze LIke I said, I have use ls -l to test the file path, it exists, and has 755 rights.

Comment: @JonathanRomer <user> is to be replaced with a real user name. I don't want to disclose the user account name here. It could be john or Jane or waht ever.

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 3):

try something like that: ([**DIR**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) is a magic constant which contains the directory of the current file)

```
include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/Menu.php';

// PHP >= 5.3
include_once __DIR__.'/Menu.php';
```

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507